# How to save and load the radiobutton state when previous button clicked?

Tags: android, radio-button, state

I am developing android quiz app like this :

[image]

This app contain 24 question, i use 4 radiogroup that oriented horizontally inside tablelayout. Each user clicks the next button, all radiogroups clear check. But i want every previous button to be clicked, the choice that the user has chosen before will reappear on the radiobutton. I've tried this code :

```
public void saveRadioButtons(){
    sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    for(RadioButton radioButton: radioButtons){
        if (radioButton.isChecked()){
            editor.putBoolean("state", radioButton.isChecked());
        }
    }
    editor.apply();
}

public void loadRadioButtons(){
    sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    for(RadioButton radioButton: radioButtons){
            radioButton.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("state", false));
    }
}
```

and the radiobutton wants to be filled automatically, but I'm confused how I can determine which radiobutton was checked before, because based on the code above all the radio buttons are true. i have tried using the if radiobutton checked then store the data of radiobutton to shared reference with string data type, so the code should be like this :

```
public void saveRadioButtons(){
    sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    for(RadioButton radioButton: radioButtons){
        if (radioButton.isChecked()){
            String value = radioButton.getText().toString();
            editor.putString("state", value);
        }
    }
    editor.apply();
}

public void loadRadioButtons(){
    sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    for(RadioButton radioButton: radioButtons){
        String state = sharedPreferences.getString("state", null);
        if (state==radioButton.getText().toString()){
            radioButton.setChecked(true);
        }
    }
}
```

But nothing happens. is there a way to determine which radiobutton has been clicked before using the first code?

and the next question is, can I use an array or global variable and not use SHAREDPREFERENCES? because if I use SHAREDPREFERENCES then i close the application, the answer will still be stored in it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a **ViewPager** with multiple **Fragments** in it. One fragment for each page. This way, when you get back to previous page, the filled RadioButtons are still in their situations.

So, what you need is a parent activity contains a ViewPager, and multiple Fragments for this ViewPager for showing questions and RadioButtons.

Good luck.

Comment: is there no other way if I want to use 1 dynamic layout ? so I don't need to make 24 layout for multiple fragments

Comment: Yes you can. I think Using FragmentPageAdapter you can add fragments to viewPager dinamically. see https://gist.github.com/cesco89/11008973 for help.

Comment: But how to load previous radiobutton state when i use a dynamic fragment?